# customize emacs sql-mode to execute sql-blocks

Tags: emacs, sql-mode

REPL in EMACS is really a great feature I love so much.
but under sql-mode, I encountered quite a few issues.

like:

1. I would like to use db3( a wrapper of db2 which can recoginze alias ), can I start a db3 shell buffer and make the sql-mode recognize it as the default evaluation buffer?
2. this is actually more important, when I send a region to the eval buffer, the eval buffer will execute the region by line break, which make my sql-code barely executable. so How would I customize the sql-mode, so that it can execute by block instead of line-break ?

==========I have find solution myself==================

for question 1: customize the sql-db2 is definitely more difficult , which I am still digging out, that envolves more work like writing plugins for emacs
==> the temporary solution is I can still connect to db2 use alias

for question 2: it turns out that db2 do have an option -t to set the termination character , which perfectly solves my question.

Comment: If you are happy with your solution, add it as an Answer and then Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==========I have find solution myself==================

for question 1: customize the sql-db2 is definitely more difficult , which I am still digging out, that envolves more work like writing plugins for emacs ==> the temporary solution is I can still connect to db2 use alias

for question 2: it turns out that db2 do have an option -t to set the termination character , which perfectly solves my question.